# How do I modify attributes within an Ionic icon?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using an `ion-icon` in my app and I'd like to be able to change some attributes within the svg dynamically. Specifically, I'm using the following battery icon and I want to change the percentage of its fill:

`<ion-icon name="battery-full-outline"></ion-icon>`

The attribute I'm interested in is the `width` attribute in the second of the two `<rect>` elements within the SVG. Using my browser tools, I've found the generated HTML to be the following:

```
<ion-icon _ngcontent-amc-c135="" name="battery-full-outline" ng-reflect-name="battery-full-outline" role="img" class="ios hydrated" aria-label="battery full outline">
   #shadow-root (open)
   <div class="icon-inner">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ionicon s-ion-icon" viewBox="0 0 
        512 512">
         <title>Battery Full</title>
         <rect x="32" y="144" width="400" height="224" rx="45.7" ry="45.7" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="ionicon-fill-none ionicon-stroke-width"></rect>
         <rect x="85.69" y="198.93" width="292.63" height="114.14" rx="4" ry="4" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="ionicon-stroke-width"></rect>
         <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M480 218.67v74.66" class="ionicon-fill-none ionicon-stroke-width"></path>
      </svg>
   </div>
</ion-icon>
```

The problem of course is that these elements are embedded within a shadow DOM, and Ionic icons don't expose any parts that the user can modify. Is there a way in Angular to get around this? I'm wondering if I can place a directive on the `ion-icon` component that would use `ElementRef` to access the underlying elements (but it seems like there are some things I haven't considered to make this work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This certainly isn't a good practice (and goes against the fundamentals of Angular), but the simplest solution I could find was just to use plain JavaScript document methods to get the `width` attribute I was looking for and to set a new value in the shadow DOM element:

```
const rect = document.querySelector('.my-icon-class').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('icon-inner svg rect)[1];
const fullWidth = rect.getAttribute('width');
const newWidth = parseFloat(fullWidth) * BATTERY_PERCENTAGE * 0.01;
rect.setAttribute('width', `${newWidth}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplest way to do it can be editing and creating your own icons. Please, check the [Ionicons](https://ionic.io/ionicons/usage) usage and see that is possible to add your own `SVG` file linked in the `<ion-icon src="/path/to/my/battery-file.svg"></ion-icon>` tags. So, creating an icon for each battery level you can use `*ngIf` condition associated to check which level to show for the users.

For example:

```
<ion-icon *ngIf="level==1" src="/path/to/my/bat-one.svg"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon *ngIf="level==2" src="/path/to/my/bat-two.svg"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon *ngIf="level==3" src="/path/to/my/bat-three.svg"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon *ngIf="level==4" src="/path/to/my/bat-four.svg"></ion-icon>
```

[image: battery level]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware that I can create custom icons, but I'd like to be able to show a fill corresponding to the exact percentage instead of resolving to one of a few fixed battery levels. Creating 100 of these icons wouldn't be reasonable either. My original question was aimed at finding out if it's possible at all to modify the icons as they are using the given frameworks. If not, I'll resort to a different approach entirely as you mentioned.

Comment: I understand you better now, so you can try a `svg` progress animation or a CSS animation to do it.

Comment: I ended up using plain JavaScript to modify the attribute within the shadow DOM. Not the best solution, but it was the easiest way and it was a workaround that I am fine with using.